# Display list of countries in form using a dropdown

Tags: entries, form, drop-down

So I'm using [this territories plugin](https://github.com/johndwells/craft.territories/) to display a list of countries in a dropdown. The issue I'm having is showing these countries within my front-end entry form.

I've used this example but it doesn't work:

```
{% for option in entry.territoryFieldHandle.options %}
    <li {% if option.selected %}class="active"{% endif %}>{{ option }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's my whole form. The other dropdowns work fine.

```
             {% set jobTypeDropdown = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('jobType') %}
        <label for="fields[jobType]">Job Type</label>
        <select name="fields[jobType]">
            {% for option in jobTypeDropdown.settings.options %}
                <option value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        {% set jobCategoryDropdown = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('jobCategory') %}
        <label for="fields[jobCategory]">Job Category</label>
        <select name="fields[jobCategory]">
            {% for option in jobCategoryDropdown.settings.options %}
                <option value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <label for="fields[country]">Country</label>
        <select name="fields[country]">
            {% for option in entry.country.options %}
                <option value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author?

Comment: Do you have an {{ entry }} variable available in the template scope? When you say it doesn't work, is it throwing an error or simply not rendering?

Answer (score 12):

This is not the answer you were looking for, but if you decide to just go with a normal drop-down, then you can paste the following into the dropdown field in the database. This would go in the `craft_fields` table, `yourCountryField` row, `settings` column. After editing the list the way you need it I would suggest removing all line-breaks using grep find/replace ('\n', ''), but it may not matter either.

```
{"options":[
{"label":"Afghanistan","value":"AF","default":""},
{"label":"Aland Islands","value":"AX","default":""},
{"label":"Albania","value":"AL","default":""},
{"label":"Algeria","value":"DZ","default":""},
{"label":"American Samoa","value":"AS","default":""},
{"label":"Andorra","value":"AD","default":""},
{"label":"Angola","value":"AO","default":""},
{"label":"Anguilla","value":"AI","default":""},
{"label":"Antarctica","value":"AQ","default":""},
{"label":"Antigua and Barbuda","value":"AG","default":""},
{"label":"Argentina","value":"AR","default":""},
{"label":"Armenia","value":"AM","default":""},
{"label":"Aruba","value":"AW","default":""},
{"label":"Australia","value":"AU","default":""},
{"label":"Austria","value":"AT","default":""},
{"label":"Azerbaijan","value":"AZ","default":""},
{"label":"Bahamas","value":"BS","default":""},
{"label":"Bahrain","value":"BH","default":""},
{"label":"Bangladesh","value":"BD","default":""},
{"label":"Barbados","value":"BB","default":""},
{"label":"Belarus","value":"BY","default":""},
{"label":"Belgium","value":"BE","default":""},
{"label":"Belize","value":"BZ","default":""},
{"label":"Benin","value":"BJ","default":""},
{"label":"Bermuda","value":"BM","default":""},
{"label":"Bhutan","value":"BT","default":""},
{"label":"Bolivia","value":"BO","default":""},
{"label":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","value":"BA","default":""},
{"label":"Botswana","value":"BW","default":""},
{"label":"Bouvet Island","value":"BV","default":""},
{"label":"Brazil","value":"BR","default":""},
{"label":"British Indian Ocean Territory","value":"IO","default":""},
{"label":"Brunei Darussalam","value":"BN","default":""},
{"label":"Bulgaria","value":"BG","default":""},
{"label":"Burkina Faso","value":"BF","default":""},
{"label":"Burundi","value":"BI","default":""},
{"label":"Cambodia","value":"KH","default":""},
{"label":"Cameroon","value":"CM","default":""},
{"label":"Canada","value":"CA","default":""},
{"label":"Cape Verde","value":"CV","default":""},
{"label":"Cayman Islands","value":"KY","default":""},
{"label":"Central African Republic","value":"CF","default":""},
{"label":"Chad","value":"TD","default":""},
{"label":"Chile","value":"CL","default":""},
{"label":"China","value":"CN","default":""},
{"label":"Christmas Island","value":"CX","default":""},
{"label":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","value":"CC","default":""},
{"label":"Colombia","value":"CO","default":""},
{"label":"Comoros","value":"KM","default":""},
{"label":"Congo","value":"CG","default":""},
{"label":"Congo, The Democratic Republic of the","value":"CD","default":""},
{"label":"Cook Islands","value":"CK","default":""},
{"label":"Costa Rica","value":"CR","default":""},
{"label":"Cote D'Ivoire","value":"CI","default":""},
{"label":"Croatia","value":"HR","default":""},
{"label":"Cuba","value":"CU","default":""},
{"label":"Cyprus","value":"CY","default":""},
{"label":"Czech Republic","value":"CZ","default":""},
{"label":"Denmark","value":"DK","default":""},
{"label":"Djibouti","value":"DJ","default":""},
{"label":"Dominica","value":"DM","default":""},
{"label":"Dominican Republic","value":"DO","default":""},
{"label":"Ecuador","value":"EC","default":""},
{"label":"Egypt","value":"EG","default":""},
{"label":"El Salvador","value":"SV","default":""},
{"label":"Equatorial Guinea","value":"GQ","default":""},
{"label":"Eritrea","value":"ER","default":""},
{"label":"Estonia","value":"EE","default":""},
{"label":"Ethiopia","value":"ET","default":""},
{"label":"Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","value":"FK","default":""},
{"label":"Faroe Islands","value":"FO","default":""},
{"label":"Fiji","value":"FJ","default":""},
{"label":"Finland","value":"FI","default":""},
{"label":"France","value":"FR","default":""},
{"label":"French Guiana","value":"GF","default":""},
{"label":"French Polynesia","value":"PF","default":""},
{"label":"French Southern Territories","value":"TF","default":""},
{"label":"Gabon","value":"GA","default":""},
{"label":"Gambia","value":"GM","default":""},
{"label":"Georgia","value":"GE","default":""},
{"label":"Germany","value":"DE","default":""},
{"label":"Ghana","value":"GH","default":""},
{"label":"Gibraltar","value":"GI","default":""},
{"label":"Greece","value":"GR","default":""},
{"label":"Greenland","value":"GL","default":""},
{"label":"Grenada","value":"GD","default":""},
{"label":"Guadeloupe","value":"GP","default":""},
{"label":"Guam","value":"GU","default":""},
{"label":"Guatemala","value":"GT","default":""},
{"label":"Guernsey","value":"GG","default":""},
{"label":"Guinea","value":"GN","default":""},
{"label":"Guinea-Bissau","value":"GW","default":""},
{"label":"Guyana","value":"GY","default":""},
{"label":"Haiti","value":"HT","default":""},
{"label":"Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands","value":"HM","default":""},
{"label":"Holy See (Vatican City State)","value":"VA","default":""},
{"label":"Honduras","value":"HN","default":""},
{"label":"Hong Kong","value":"HK","default":""},
{"label":"Hungary","value":"HU","default":""},
{"label":"Iceland","value":"IS","default":""},
{"label":"India","value":"IN","default":""},
{"label":"Indonesia","value":"ID","default":""},
{"label":"Iran, Islamic Republic Of","value":"IR","default":""},
{"label":"Iraq","value":"IQ","default":""},
{"label":"Ireland","value":"IE","default":""},
{"label":"Isle of Man","value":"IM","default":""},
{"label":"Israel","value":"IL","default":""},
{"label":"Italy","value":"IT","default":""},
{"label":"Jamaica","value":"JM","default":""},
{"label":"Japan","value":"JP","default":""},
{"label":"Jersey","value":"JE","default":""},
{"label":"Jordan","value":"JO","default":""},
{"label":"Kazakhstan","value":"KZ","default":""},
{"label":"Kenya","value":"KE","default":""},
{"label":"Kiribati","value":"KI","default":""},
{"label":"Korea, Democratic People's Republic of","value":"KP","default":""},
{"label":"Korea, Republic of","value":"KR","default":""},
{"label":"Kuwait","value":"KW","default":""},
{"label":"Kyrgyzstan","value":"KG","default":""},
{"label":"Lao People's Democratic Republic","value":"LA","default":""},
{"label":"Latvia","value":"LV","default":""},
{"label":"Lebanon","value":"LB","default":""},
{"label":"Lesotho","value":"LS","default":""},
{"label":"Liberia","value":"LR","default":""},
{"label":"Libyan Arab Jamahiriya","value":"LY","default":""},
{"label":"Liechtenstein","value":"LI","default":""},
{"label":"Lithuania","value":"LT","default":""},
{"label":"Luxembourg","value":"LU","default":""},
{"label":"Macao","value":"MO","default":""},
{"label":"Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of","value":"MK","default":""},
{"label":"Madagascar","value":"MG","default":""},
{"label":"Malawi","value":"MW","default":""},
{"label":"Malaysia","value":"MY","default":""},
{"label":"Maldives","value":"MV","default":""},
{"label":"Mali","value":"ML","default":""},
{"label":"Malta","value":"MT","default":""},
{"label":"Marshall Islands","value":"MH","default":""},
{"label":"Martinique","value":"MQ","default":""},
{"label":"Mauritania","value":"MR","default":""},
{"label":"Mauritius","value":"MU","default":""},
{"label":"Mayotte","value":"YT","default":""},
{"label":"Mexico","value":"MX","default":""},
{"label":"Micronesia, Federated States of","value":"FM","default":""},
{"label":"Moldova, Republic of","value":"MD","default":""},
{"label":"Monaco","value":"MC","default":""},
{"label":"Mongolia","value":"MN","default":""},
{"label":"Montserrat","value":"MS","default":""},
{"label":"Morocco","value":"MA","default":""},
{"label":"Mozambique","value":"MZ","default":""},
{"label":"Myanmar","value":"MM","default":""},
{"label":"Namibia","value":"NA","default":""},
{"label":"Nauru","value":"NR","default":""},
{"label":"Nepal","value":"NP","default":""},
{"label":"Netherlands","value":"NL","default":""},
{"label":"Netherlands Antilles","value":"AN","default":""},
{"label":"New Caledonia","value":"NC","default":""},
{"label":"New Zealand","value":"NZ","default":""},
{"label":"Nicaragua","value":"NI","default":""},
{"label":"Niger","value":"NE","default":""},
{"label":"Nigeria","value":"NG","default":""},
{"label":"Niue","value":"NU","default":""},
{"label":"Norfolk Island","value":"NF","default":""},
{"label":"Northern Mariana Islands","value":"MP","default":""},
{"label":"Norway","value":"NO","default":""},
{"label":"Oman","value":"OM","default":""},
{"label":"Pakistan","value":"PK","default":""},
{"label":"Palau","value":"PW","default":""},
{"label":"Palestinian Territory, Occupied","value":"PS","default":""},
{"label":"Panama","value":"PA","default":""},
{"label":"Papua New Guinea","value":"PG","default":""},
{"label":"Paraguay","value":"PY","default":""},
{"label":"Peru","value":"PE","default":""},
{"label":"Philippines","value":"PH","default":""},
{"label":"Pitcairn","value":"PN","default":""},
{"label":"Poland","value":"PL","default":""},
{"label":"Portugal","value":"PT","default":""},
{"label":"Puerto Rico","value":"PR","default":""},
{"label":"Qatar","value":"QA","default":""},
{"label":"Reunion","value":"RE","default":""},
{"label":"Romania","value":"RO","default":""},
{"label":"Russian Federation","value":"RU","default":""},
{"label":"Rwanda","value":"RW","default":""},
{"label":"Saint Helena","value":"SH","default":""},
{"label":"Saint Kitts and Nevis","value":"KN","default":""},
{"label":"Saint Lucia","value":"LC","default":""},
{"label":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon","value":"PM","default":""},
{"label":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","value":"VC","default":""},
{"label":"Samoa","value":"WS","default":""},
{"label":"San Marino","value":"SM","default":""},
{"label":"Sao Tome and Principe","value":"ST","default":""},
{"label":"Saudi Arabia","value":"SA","default":""},
{"label":"Senegal","value":"SN","default":""},
{"label":"Serbia and Montenegro","value":"CS","default":""},
{"label":"Seychelles","value":"SC","default":""},
{"label":"Sierra Leone","value":"SL","default":""},
{"label":"Singapore","value":"SG","default":""},
{"label":"Slovakia","value":"SK","default":""},
{"label":"Slovenia","value":"SI","default":""},
{"label":"Solomon Islands","value":"SB","default":""},
{"label":"Somalia","value":"SO","default":""},
{"label":"South Africa","value":"ZA","default":""},
{"label":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands","value":"GS","default":""},
{"label":"Spain","value":"ES","default":""},
{"label":"Sri Lanka","value":"LK","default":""},
{"label":"Sudan","value":"SD","default":""},
{"label":"Suriname","value":"SR","default":""},
{"label":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen","value":"SJ","default":""},
{"label":"Swaziland","value":"SZ","default":""},
{"label":"Sweden","value":"SE","default":""},
{"label":"Switzerland","value":"CH","default":""},
{"label":"Syrian Arab Republic","value":"SY","default":""},
{"label":"Taiwan, Province of China","value":"TW","default":""},
{"label":"Tajikistan","value":"TJ","default":""},
{"label":"Tanzania, United Republic of","value":"TZ","default":""},
{"label":"Thailand","value":"TH","default":""},
{"label":"Timor-Leste","value":"TL","default":""},
{"label":"Togo","value":"TG","default":""},
{"label":"Tokelau","value":"TK","default":""},
{"label":"Tonga","value":"TO","default":""},
{"label":"Trinidad and Tobago","value":"TT","default":""},
{"label":"Tunisia","value":"TN","default":""},
{"label":"Turkey","value":"TR","default":""},
{"label":"Turkmenistan","value":"TM","default":""},
{"label":"Turks and Caicos Islands","value":"TC","default":""},
{"label":"Tuvalu","value":"TV","default":""},
{"label":"Uganda","value":"UG","default":""},
{"label":"Ukraine","value":"UA","default":""},
{"label":"United Arab Emirates","value":"AE","default":""},
{"label":"United Kingdom","value":"GB","default":""},
{"label":"United States","value":"US","default":""},
{"label":"United States Minor Outlying Islands","value":"UM","default":""},
{"label":"Uruguay","value":"UY","default":""},
{"label":"Uzbekistan","value":"UZ","default":""},
{"label":"Vanuatu","value":"VU","default":""},
{"label":"Venezuela","value":"VE","default":""},
{"label":"Viet Nam","value":"VN","default":""},
{"label":"Virgin Islands, British","value":"VG","default":""},
{"label":"Virgin Islands, U.S.","value":"VI","default":""},
{"label":"Wallis and Futuna","value":"WF","default":""},
{"label":"Western Sahara","value":"EH","default":""},
{"label":"Yemen","value":"YE","default":""},
{"label":"Zambia","value":"ZM","default":""},
{"label":"Zimbabwe","value":"ZW","default":""}
]}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for :) thanks, ps working without removing line brakes

Comment: Glad it worked @Davor. And thanks for the follow up on line breaks.

Comment: Ha, one of those times when you think 'It's a longshot but I'll just Google this before subjecting myself to this tedium...' So glad I did...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the drop down options in [Territories Dropdown Plugin](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/territories-fieldtype) are not automatically available in templates.
It need to be accessed through a field on an element. You're currently trying to access it through 'entry' which i assume doesn't exist in your template (as you would have copied this part).

eg. I'm using it on projects in my template:

```
{% for option in project.country.options %}
<option {% if option.selected %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ option }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

For me 'project' is an [entry in my section](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/fields) 'projects' which has been declared above and i have [given it the field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/fields) 'country' of type 'Territories - Dropdown' in the admin panel.

---

If you want to access the options with out an instance of an entry you'll still need to [create a field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/fields) with the type 'Territories - Dropdown'. Then replace 'country' in the code below with the handle you give your field.

```
{% for option in craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('country').getFieldType.options %}
<option value="{{ option }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Many thanks Jered for the example. I found that outputting {{ option }} caused an array to string conversion error and I needed to use {{ option.value }} instead of just {{ option }} to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really address the problem either, but for anyone looking for "States" data (to replicate what Douglas McDonald did), here it is:

```
{"options":[{"label":"Alabama","value":"AL","default":""},{"label":"Alaska","value":"AK","default":""},{"label":"Arizona","value":"AZ","default":""},{"label":"Arkansas","value":"AR","default":""},{"label":"California","value":"CA","default":""},{"label":"Colorado","value":"CO","default":""},{"label":"Connecticut","value":"CT","default":""},{"label":"Delaware","value":"DE","default":""},{"label":"District of Columbia","value":"DC","default":""},{"label":"Florida","value":"FL","default":""},{"label":"Georgia","value":"GA","default":""},{"label":"Hawaii","value":"HI","default":""},{"label":"Idaho","value":"ID","default":""},{"label":"Illinois","value":"IL","default":""},{"label":"Indiana","value":"IN","default":""},{"label":"Iowa","value":"IA","default":""},{"label":"Kansas","value":"KS","default":""},{"label":"Kentucky","value":"KY","default":""},{"label":"Louisiana","value":"LA","default":""},{"label":"Maine","value":"ME","default":""},{"label":"Maryland","value":"MD","default":""},{"label":"Massachusetts","value":"MA","default":""},{"label":"Michigan","value":"MI","default":""},{"label":"Minnesota","value":"MN","default":""},{"label":"Mississippi","value":"MS","default":""},{"label":"Missouri","value":"MO","default":""},{"label":"Montana","value":"MT","default":""},{"label":"Nebraska","value":"NE","default":""},{"label":"Nevada","value":"NV","default":""},{"label":"New Hampshire","value":"NH","default":""},{"label":"New Jersey","value":"NJ","default":""},{"label":"New Mexico","value":"NM","default":""},{"label":"New York","value":"NY","default":""},{"label":"North Carolina","value":"NC","default":""},{"label":"North Dakota","value":"ND","default":""},{"label":"Ohio","value":"OH","default":""},{"label":"Oklahoma","value":"OK","default":""},{"label":"Oregon","value":"OR","default":""},{"label":"Pennsylvania","value":"PA","default":""},{"label":"Rhode Island","value":"RI","default":""},{"label":"South Carolina","value":"SC","default":""},{"label":"South Dakota","value":"SD","default":""},{"label":"Tennessee","value":"TN","default":""},{"label":"Texas","value":"TX","default":""},{"label":"Utah","value":"UT","default":""},{"label":"Vermont","value":"VT","default":""},{"label":"Virginia","value":"VA","default":""},{"label":"Washington","value":"WA","default":""},{"label":"West Virginia","value":"WV","default":""},{"label":"Wisconsin","value":"WI","default":""},{"label":"Wyoming","value":"WY","default":""}]}
```

1. Create a dropdown field.
2. Navigate to the `craft_fields` table
3. Locate the row with your `states` handle
4. Add the data to the `settings` column
5. Output states in a dropdown

   ```
   {% for state in craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('states').getFieldType.options %}
       <option value="{{ state.value }}">{{ state.label }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Even better, create a reusable macro:

```
{% macro stateDropdownOptions(currentState) %}
    <option>Select One</option>
    {% for state in craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('states').getFieldType.options %}
        <option value="{{ state.value }}"{{ currentState is defined and state.value == currentState ? ' selected' : '' }}>
            {{ state.label }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

and use it:

```
{% import 'macros/form' as formMacros %}

...

<select name="states">
    {{ formMacros.stateDropdownOptions(row.state) }}
</select>
```